# setState on Array value React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio, reactjs

Given the sequence below, I failed to set this.state.arr to data received from request, I suppose my mistake is in the way I try to set arr. How could I achieve wanted result?

**EDIT:** `var data = [{
  "name": "AlphaBank",
  "curs": 3.8549,
  "cursVanzare": 4.0741,
  "day": 20
}, {
  "name": "AlphaBank",
  "curs": 3.8579,
  "cursVanzare": 4.0774,
  "day": 21
}]`

```
var copyValue = "";


var TableComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { sn: "", fn: "", arr: [] }
  },

  componentWillMount: function () {
    $.getJSON("api/data/GetData").done(function (data) {
        copyValue = data[0].name; //data-array of Objects
        this.setState({fn:copyValue, arr: data.slice(0)})
    }.bind(this))
    this.setState({ sn: "value" });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (<div className="container">
      {this.state.sn} {this.state.fn} {this.state.arr[0].name}
    </div>);
  }
})
```

Comment: could you post how `data` looks like?

Comment: data is Array of 30 Objects  with { name : string , secondProp: string, thirdProp: int }

Comment: I'm getting problems with request : XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: off course, you must use code from fiddle in your environment

Comment: so far: sn,fn -ok , arr- gets data in setState, then in render it comes with value of InitialState

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107340/discussion-between-meta4-and-alexander).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stupid mistake was declaring **arr: [ ]** while taking in consideration incoming data it should have been defined as **arr: [{ }]** (Thanks to [Alexander T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367138/alexander-t) for help in pointing out the mistake).